# Power supply issue with LM384 audio amp

Tags: power-supply, power, amplifier, audio

I made an audio amp using the LM384 :
[image: lm384 circuit]

My soldering skills aren't great but eventually the circuit itself doesn't look too bad.
To power it, I used an old laptop power supply (18.5VDC - the datasheet of the LM384 says it can be fed with voltages form 16 to 22VDC). The supply is working, I tested it with a DMM.

The problem is, when I wired the supply to the circuit, nothing came out of the speaker.
I checked the voltage drop between Vcc and ground, it was around 2V (quite steady).

So my question is : could the problem be related to input impedance? The one of this circuit being most likely far away from the one of a computer, I guess.

As always, any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: The voltage from Vcc to ground is only 2V? There's your problem right there. Why is it not the 18.5V you say your power supply produces?

Comment: First thing to do is disconnect your power supply and check that it is giving you the 18.5V. Next thing is check for any short-circuits.

Comment: I did, power supply gives 18.5V and there's no short between Vcc and gnd. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Vcc should be equal to the supply- 18.5V. If it's 2V then something is seriously wrong (and probably getting very hot).

Chances are there is a short or the chip has been permanently damaged.

This is not the cause of the problem you describe, but if you are not using the pot put a 10K resistor from the input to ground to provide a DC path for the input bias current.

Comment: Thank you. 

I retried, it's still 2V and not getting hot.

The DMM shows no short between Vcc and the ground and I'm using the pot.

Comment: So it is 18V then you connect the circuit and it drops to 2V?

Comment: Yes that's exactly it

Comment: Either there is a short, the 0.1uF cap or the chip are dead. Assuming it's as shown (not reversed or something like that). Nothing else will drag down the power supply like that.